# Produce a Python class which computes the n power of x, where x and n are both integer

Tags: python, class

my code is like this

```
import math 
class power():
  def _pow_(self,x,n):
  self.x = x
  self.n = n
  return self.x**self.n

x = int(input("Enter the value of x: "))
n = int(input("Enter the value of n: "))
obj=power(x,n)

print(obj._pow_())
```

and i got an error like this:power() takes no arguments.and when i delete x,n(obj=power()) this time the error:_ pow _() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'x' and 'n' is.where am i doing wrong?

Comment: pass x and n to `_pow_`

Comment: Read about classes and `__init__()`

Comment: Your indentation is off.  The posted code will give an error.

Comment: This shouldn't be a class at all. Why don't you write a simple function instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to import the `math` module for that operation.

Look this code:

```
class IntPower:
    def __init__(self, x: int, n: int):
        self._n = n
        self._x = x

    @property
    def value(self):
        return self._x ** self._n


if __name__ == "__main__":
    power = IntPower(x=10, n=2)
    print(power.value)
```

Obviously this class isn't useful, it serves only as an exercise.

Documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html